# IF ELSE in react(If the condition is correct, take me to another page)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am storing some data in array.
which is gonna be like this

```
       datas[
       password:"dfsdfsd",
       username : "dfgdgdfg55555",

       password:"deep",
       username : "dfgdgdfg56556",

       password:"hello",
       username : "dfgdgdfg65",

       password:"hello1234",
       username : "dfgdgdfg123"
     ]
```

now i want to camapare the username.
and i am trying like it and want if the condition is true(take me to another page) but don't know how to do that.

```
  checkCred(){
    var details_array = this.state.datas1 ;
    console.log(details_array);
    for(var i=0; i < details_array.length; i++) {
        var currentObject = details_array[i];
        if (this.email.value === currentObject.username) {
            console.log('yes done it');
            window.location = '/Index';// this is not working and think window.location is stupid methed...
            // please guide me if you have any better idea than this
        }

    }
  }
   <input ref={(e) => this.email = e} name="email" type="email" /><br/>
```

Am I doing correct way or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make following changes to work as per expectations,

```
var details_array = this.state.datas ;
for(var i=0; i < details_array.length; i++){
 var currentObject = details_array[i];
 if (this.email.value === currentObject.username){
    console.log('yes done');
 }
}
```

Note: hope you have data in details_array.

Comment: now i am doing it like this. then it only taking last value of the array.. not others...